# AppendChild and insertAdjacentHtml difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, appendchild

Why insertAdjacentHTML not working here, but appendChild is working fine?

```
   mobileMenuItems.forEach((val, i) => {
         val.addEventListener('click', e => {
             e.preventDefault();
             console.log(val);
             m.innerHTML = '';
             m.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', val);
             m.appendChild(val);
         });
    });
```

Comment: Because `insertAdjacentHTML` expects a string. Use [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) if you want to insert an element instead of a string.

Comment: The names of the methods are a giveaway. HTML is a string that defines the DOM. Elements are object representations of the DOM.